# Simplifying an arbitrary constant.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

Could someone explain me this simplification?

[image]

I cannot understand exact reason why $c_1$ is before $\exp$ function without being in another one.

Screenshot presents end of solution of this differential equation:
$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=(x^2−2)(y−4)$$

I will be very grateful for the solution of it entirely with all the steps even in the form of a photo of a sheet of paper

Comment: $e^{c_{1}}$ is itself a constant i.e $e^{c_{1}} = c_{2}$. To solve the ODE, just separate and integrate $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (x^{2} - 2)(y - 4) \implies \frac{y'}{y - 4} = (x^{2} - 2) \implies \int \frac{y'}{y - 4} dx = \int (x^{2} - 2) dx$$

Comment: If there are no partial derivatives involved, then you should remove the partial-differential-equations tag.

Comment: @MatthewCassell So I'm right this c before function isn't equal to c in exponentiation and naming them same is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the $c_{1}$ before the exponential function is not the same $c_{1}$ that is in the exponential function. Naming them the same is not an issue though; we often relabel things in maths. There is nothing wrong in letting $e^{c_{1}} \to c_{1}$ _**provided it is clear to the reader**_. This is why we often, for clarity, use another constant name rather than relabelling i.e letting $e^{c_{1}} = c_{2}$ (especially in high school and undergraduate courses where there is a lot of potential for confusion).

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it myself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thx i missed your first comment